# Для чего нужна зависимость commons-lang в maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

Просматривая разные проекты обнаружил что часто при настройке spring boot вставляется зависимость commons-lang

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Объясните пожалуйста для чего она нужна?

Comment: [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) provides extra functionality for classes in java.lang.

Comment: Очень полезная библиотека, советую изучить.